# Killing Zombie Process without killing its parent

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not very skillfull on this.
I have a wheezy distro installed, with basics so i can't use 'awk' command in scripts. I can't update or install anything on the system, so there are some difficulties.

Anyhow, I have this script which accepts an argument that can be START/STOP/STATUS.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "$1" = "START" ] && ./bin/Process1

if [ "$1" = "STOP" ]
then
  getprocess=`ps -ef|grep Process1`
  set $getprocess
  pid=$2
  kill -9 $pid
fi

if [ "$1" = "STATUS" ]
then
  if pgrep "Process1" > /dev/null
  then
    echo "Running"
  else
    echo "Stopped"
  fi
fi
```

So the script RUNs/KILLs a process whose name is known. The problem is that as I have it now, it doesn't kills it completely but remains as a ZOMBIE process pending from the script. So when running STATUS it pops up that it is running.

Why my script doesn't dies after execution, or how can a clean up effectively this proccess?

Comment: Pretty sure you have to kill the parent to get rid of zombies. I'd suggest fixing the process.

Comment: the thing is, shouldn't it die after execution? can i kill the script from inside itself?

Comment: A "zombie" process is already dead. All of it is gone, except for an entry in the process table containing the exit status, to be retrieved by the parent process.

Comment: But it's a problem it appears in the process table. If i START & KILL it twice, it will try to kill the zombie instead, and so on multiple processes executions start to pile on. In addition, on STATUS it will find the zombie and echo "running"

Comment: @Joster Again, fix the process.

Comment: what's `set \`ps -ef|grep Process1\`` supposed to do?

Comment: Do you have a reason for using -9? You might be killing the parent without giving it a chance to reap it's children (which would cause zombies). Have you tried just killing with -TERM?

Comment: @ccarton I've tried, but happens the same

Comment: @123 sorry, don't know what you mean by fixing the process